# Is IPsec IND-CCA secure provided the used block cipher is a pseudorandom function?

Tags: authenticated-encryption, modes-of-operation, pseudo-random-function, ipsec

I am trying to solve the question whether
"***IPsec is IND-CCA secure provided the used block cipher is a pseudorandom function***" (with IPsec using a variant of Encrypt-then-MAC)

As a resource I am given the paper
[Mihir Bellare & Chanathip Namprempre (2000). Authenticate
andd Encryption: Relations among notions and analysis of the generic composition paradigm](https://eprint.iacr.org/2000/025)

where I should focus on Theorem 3.2, which is the following implication:
INT-CTXT $\wedge$ IND-CPA $\rightarrow$ IND-CCA

Accordingly, I am trying to verify that the antecedent of the implication holds when using a pseudorandom function as a block cipher. I am currently stuck with the part whether the property of IND-CPA security holds. If I understood it correctly, the IND-CPA security depends on the mode of operation in which the pseudorandom function is used. 
In our lecture it was mentioned that an encryption scheme using a pseudorandom function as block cipher is indeed CPA-secure if the CTR mode (with a randomly chosen initial ctr) or the CBC mode is used. However, as far as I know it does *not* hold for other modes.

Therefore, I would like to know which mode of operation is used by IPsec and whether my approach makes sense.

Comment: Did you mean pseudo-random-*permutation*?

Comment: No, the block cipher should really be a pseudorandom _function_, not a pseudo-random-_permutation_.

Comment: But why are you mentioning CBC mode then, which is not compatible with PRFs? The proper model for a block cipher is a (strong) PRP. Since PRPs can approximate PRFs up to the birthday bound we can use PRPs even in PRF assuming modes like CTR.

Comment: In the lecture we were told that if we have a PRF and the  message length is fixed, then the CBC-mode with a random IV for each message is IND-CPA secure. That is why I mentioned the CBC mode and thought that it was compatible with PRFs. Further, in the exercise it is explicitely stated that the block cipher has to be a PRF. Therefore, I have to prove it for a PRF and not a PRP.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to know which mode of operation is used by IPsec

That depends on what is negotiated; if we assume we're using AES as the block cipher, then the standard modes (that is, ones which have transform numbers assigned by IANA) are CBC, CTR and GCM.

> and whether my approach makes sense.

Sounds good to me.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
What I still need to know is which modes are used in the case of a pseudorandom function as a block cipher. Your examples refer to AES as the block cipher if I understood it correctly. Also the encryption scheme must be EtA and not AtE or E&A, are the modes you mentioned all EtA?

Comment: @SkyPassaro: technically speaking, GCM is neither EtA nor AtE nor E&A, but instead is a combined mode (which does both encryption and authentication; all the details are hidden within the mode).  As for CBC and CTR mode, the modes themselves don't do authentication; however the standard ways of doing the transform is, in fact, EtA.  However, there's nothing in the RFCs that say that you *have* to do it that way (or, in fact, that you have to do authentication at all); if you somehow configure things to do AH and then an outer ESP (without authentication), you're in AtE-land.

Comment: @SkyPassaro: this imples that you can't prove IND-CCA for all modes of operation (that's actually known not to be true; for example, you *don't* have to encrypt).  Instead, you need to make assumptions about which IPsec transforms are being used (and in which order).